# MySQl I need to make a column unique only for certain values of another column

Tags: mysql, triggers, unique-constraint

I have two columns Name,IsDelete in a table T

There can only be unique names for IsDelete=0

For IsDelete=1, there can be duplicate names.

I'm using this query

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix ON T(Name) WHERE IsDelete = 0;
```

But I'm getting the error,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE IsDeleted = 0 at line 1

How can I use triggers to solve this?

Comment: I think indexes are created on columns not parts of columns. Therefore you can't use a where clause in this statement. I think this is something you best solve with stored procedures or application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Unique indices must have references to ALL RECORDS.
They cannot be conditional creation of unique index construction.

The requirement you set could be covered by another table structure where the deleted or not is not part of the record.

You must redesign the data to use a master table with unique IDs and alter the current to link to the master table.

It is a basic theoretical lesson in data normalisation.

Comment: Isnt there a way to create a trigger that would stop insertion of duplicate data when IsDeleted=0? The trigger will not be generated when IsDeleted=1. I'm looking for that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so I got a trigger that would check for the condition to be true.

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER testing4
BEFORE INSERT ON biomitra_user 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (select mobile_number from biomitra_user where is_deleted=0) THEN 
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate';
else 
set new.mobile_number=new.mobile_number;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

This is working fine